# Get array value from AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a script that reads a JSON file then populates an array with the name property of each element.

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
var a = [];

var myMethod = function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "numbers.json",
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(data){
            for(i in data){
                a.push(data[i].name);
            }
        }
    });
}

myMethod();
console.log(a[2]); // console.log() returns "undefined"
</script>
```

**JSON**

```
[
    {"name" : "One"},
    {"name" : "Two"},
    {"name" : "Three"},
    {"name" : "Four"},
    {"name" : "Five"}
]
```

I cant't access a specific index of this array. The console log always returns *undefined*. I've tried to add `.then()` after my ajax call, but it doesn't work too.

Comment: your console.log is running before ajax request completed. check in ajax success function where you are creating a array, you will get it

Comment: what is there in number.json? can you post the dummy data here ?so that i can create a simple code snippet for you

Comment: The JSON is given already

Comment: your code will also work if you will set ajax property "async:false"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll wanna do something like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
var a = [];

var myMethod = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "numbers.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            for (i in data) {
                a.push(data[i].name);
            }
            handleData();
        }
    });
}

function handleData() {
    console.log(a[2]);
}

myMethod();
</script>
```

Javascript won't wait for all of your code to run line by line, so for asynchronous calls you'll need a seperate function to handle data OR to handle the data within the success callback. Another function would be cleaner though depending on what you want to do with the data.

Answer (score 4):

Your `console.log(a[2]);` runs before `AJAX` finishing processing, because of `AJAX`'s asynchronous nature, that's why it returns `undefined`. Put the console.log inside `AJAX` success. See the working snippet:

```js
var a = [];

var myMethod = function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "https://api.myjson.com/bins/b4bnr",
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(data){
            for(i in data){
                a.push(data[i].name);   
            }
           console.log(a[2]);
        }
    });
}

myMethod();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can read more about how AJAX works **[here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)**.

Answer (score 2):

Your're running an asynchronous request using `$.ajax` function so you should wait for the response then call the `console.log` inside success callback when the response is received from the server-side else the `console.log` will not work since the query is pending :

```
success : function(data){
     for(i in data){
         a.push(data[i].name);
     }
     console.log(a[2]);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This question has been asked multiple times over the years, and we have a canonical duplicate for it. Any reason you're not using your gold badge to mark this as a duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

The myMethod function completes when the ajax call completes and it moves on to the next line which is the console.log. The success only executes after the request to numbers.json returns. Try this:

```
var a = [];

var myMethod = function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "numbers.json",
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(data){
            for(i in data){
                a.push(data[i].name);
            }
            console.log(a[2]);
        }
    });
}

myMethod();
```